# How to get boolean of JCheckBoxMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, jmenuitem

I have this JCheckBoxMenuItem as a field:

```
private JCheckBoxMenuItem chckbxmntmDisableSending = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Disable Sending");
```

I need to find out whether it is checked or not some time later, when doing something else (pressing the send button, basically). How do I get the value of this?

I've googled 'check value of JCheckBoxMenuItem', 'get boolean JCheckBoxMenuItem', others. I've also looked at the documentation, which says something about `getState()`, but I am under the impression that `getState()` only gives you whether it is selected by the mouse or not.

How *do* you get the current boolean value of a JCheckbox menu item? That is, whether it is checked or not?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a read of [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: And perhaps you should have read his question before posting a RTFM answer… since his question is NOT answered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Javadocs, the `isSelected()` method will also return a boolean value for its state.

Comment: Wouldn't that boolean be whether it is selected by the mouse? Or no?

Comment: @ifly6 It returns the state of the `JCheckBoxMenuItem`'s selected state, regardless of how it was set

Comment: The isSelected() method is inherited from AbstractButton. Here is some more info if you want:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected()

Comment: And, by `selected`, you mean whether it is selected by the mouse?

Comment: @ifly6 *"And, by selected, you mean whether it is selected by the mouse?"* In as it will return `true` if it has been "checked" or `false` when it's not.  How that's achieved is irrelevent

Comment: Then how does `isSelected()` work for a JButton? You can't check that button.

Comment: `isSelected()` should be used for toggle buttons such as JCheckBox.

Comment: So basically the getState()/isSelected() methods are worthless in an ActionListener for a JCheckBoxMenuItem because they'll always return true... because the mouse "selected" this item in order to click it… What the OP (and I) want to know is if the checkmark is displayed or not.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [JCheckBoxMenu Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBoxMenuItem.html%20%22JCheckBoxMenu)

> Either isSelected/setSelected or getState/setState can be used to determine/specify the menu item's selection state. The preferred methods are isSelected and setSelected, which work for all menus and buttons. The getState and setState methods exist for compatibility with other component sets.

To determine when it changes state, add an [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) to your JCheckBoxMenuItem via [addItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addItemListener(java.awt.event.ItemListener)).

Comment: So, you mean, add the ItemListener, make a boolean field, and have the ItemListener lambda expression basically say `if (field) { field = false; } else { field = true; }`?

Comment: The OP (and I) don't care if it's selected or not… we want to know if the checkmark is visible or not… getState & isSelected return true if it was selected... as in "just clicked on by the mouse"... so they're always true inside an ActionListener (since it's called when the mouse is click on that object). Totally worthless in determining if an item is check marked or not.